# How to uniformly fill a volume of a convexHull given by a list of 3d points?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, convex-hull

I have a convexHull given by a list of 3d points generated by [scipy.spatial.ConvexHull](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html).

I want that entire volume uniformly filled with 3d points, in some efficient manner.

If i had a fast way of knowing if a point is inside or out of a convexHull, I could maybe vectorize going over each voxel in some resolution and returning its center if it is "inside" or returning nothing for that voxel if it is "outside".

---

**Example:**

for 2d points, like in scipy's example of ConvexHull,

[image: scipy's example]

I would like to compute a list of points which are evenly spaced inside the red line.

How can this be done rather efficiently?

Comment: Do you have access to the `ConvexHull` object itself or only the vertices?

Comment: @paul panzer i have access.

Comment: Then you can use the `.equations` attribute which contains surface normals to test for in/out. it looks to me like you have to provide the points you want to check in "homogeneous" coordinates or in plain English append a `1` to each points' coordinates. Then matrix multiply and check the columns of the result. An all positiive column indicates an interior point. A single negative coordinate is enough to put you outside, a nonnegative but not strictly positive column means you are somewhere on the surface.

Comment: Or maybe the other way round, i.e. negative where I said positive and vice versa.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Could you show code? I don't quite understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some (unoptimized) sample code demonstrating the use of the `.equations` attribute which contains surface normals to the convex hull.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial

## set up example ##
# create sample points
np.random.seed(17)
samples = np.random.uniform(-5,5,(100,2))
# pick convex subset
outline = samples[(samples**2).sum(1)<4]
outline = spatial.ConvexHull(outline)
# choose tolerance for detection of boundary points
eps = 1e-9

## classify ##
outside = (outline.equations@np.c_[samples, np.ones(len(samples))].T > eps).any(0)
inside = (outline.equations@np.c_[samples, np.ones(len(samples))].T < -eps).all(0)
boundary = ~(outside|inside)

## plot ##
import pylab
closed = np.tile(outline.points[outline.vertices],(2,1))
closed = closed[:len(closed)//2+1]
pylab.plot(*closed.T,'b')
pylab.plot(*samples[outside].T,'og')
pylab.plot(*samples[inside].T,'or')
pylab.plot(*samples[boundary].T,'oy')
pylab.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for that! Unfortunately We are using python 2.7 still... is there a quick replacement for `@`?

Comment: @Gulzar there are `matmul` and `dot`.

Comment: could you explain the use of `.c_` here? I found this part not clear, even though it ended up working for me.

Comment: @Gulzar `c_` is column stacker; here it adds a column of ones at the end of `samples`

Comment: it works! 
However... I noticed it checks for every single point, for every single equation. I wonder if there is a quicker way. One i can think of the top of my mind is going over a dimension (say x) and finding the first and last point in the hull. the others are in with no need to check. the search can be done o(nlogn). Is there an even quicker way, maybe some smart simplex method?

Comment: @Gulzar I dont know. Perhaps you could start with a coarse grid and recursively cut each cube that is not completely in or completely out into 8 equal subcubes.